# L1 / Variational Distance between distributions

Tags: st.statistics, edit-distance

My statistics knowledge is somewhat poor, so I have to ask one (dumb) question.

Let $\beta$ be a real number in the interval $\big[0, \frac{1}{2}\big)$ and $\mathcal{D}_1, \mathcal{D}_2, \mathcal{D}_3$ be three distributions over a space $\mathcal{X}$, with the property that $\mathcal{D}_1 = \beta \cdot \mathcal{D}_2 + (1-\beta) \cdot \mathcal{D}_3$. What is the [statistical variational distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$?

Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the relation between total variation and $L_1$/$\ell_1$ distance of the probability/distribution/mass functions, we have
$$\begin{align}
d_{\rm TV}(D_1, D_2) &= \frac{1}{2}\lVert D_1-D_2\rVert_1
= \frac{1}{2}\lVert \beta D_2 +(1-\beta)D_3 - D_2\rVert_1\\
&= \frac{1-\beta}{2}\lVert D_3 - D_2\rVert_1
= (1-\beta)d_{\rm TV}(D_2, D_3).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is that also available for an infinite probability space?

Comment: @tutifresh Yes, it is.